# How do I remove the loading icon after the image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use lazy loading to load the images with the centered background loading icons, but I felt unnecessary to include the lazy loading effect in this question. I want to remove the loading icon after the image is loaded because the smaller images may not cover the loading icon.

I use the same external CSS file for loading icons. None of the closest solutions worked for me.

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="lazy" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn7VW.jpg" alt="Large Image" width="800" height="380" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="lazy" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsJCI.jpg" alt="Small Image" width="250" height="180" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW2VY.gif) no-repeat center;
min-height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't implement it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `onload` event of image, inside it remove class wrapper as

```
$(".lazy").on('load', function() { $('.wrapper').removeClass('wrapper'); })
```

Update: if you want to remove only loading for each image change to remove parent class only.

```
$(this).parent().removeClass('wrapper');
```

```js
$(".lazy").on('load', function() { $(this).parent().removeClass('wrapper'); })
```

```css
.wrapper {
background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW2VY.gif) no-repeat center;
min-height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="lazy" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn7VW.jpg" alt="Large Image" width="800" height="380" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="lazy" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsJCI.jpg" alt="Small Image" width="250" height="180" />
</div>
```

Comment: The problem in your solution is that when one of the images is loaded, all the loading icons for all other images are removed. You can try adding some more images.

Comment: I updated answer, should use $(this).parent().removeClass('wrapper');

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem has been resolved now.